# How to use FunctionType to define a function that takes positional arguments?

Tags: python, function

I'm practicing the alternative way of defining functions in Python, using FunctionType. I can create this way a simple function that prints `hello world`:

```
from types import FunctionType

foo = FunctionType(compile("print('hello world')", '', 'exec'), globals())

foo()
```

This function does not take positional arguments:

```
from types import FunctionType

foo = FunctionType(compile("print('hello world')", '', 'exec'), globals())

foo('bar')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/test_FunctionType.py", line 5, in <module>
    foo('bar')
TypeError: <module>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

How to use FunctionType to define a function that takes positional arguments?

Comment: Here's one way to do it:

    from types import FunctionType
    foo = FunctionType(compile("def foo(name): print('hello '+name)", '', 'exec'), globals())()
    foo("name")

Basically, you create a function that returns a function with arguments and use it.

Note the function call at the end of the `foo = FunctionType...` line